# Encrypting mapped network drives in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, disk-encryption, bitlocker

I have Win Server 2012 and the drives of one of the HDDs connected to it are mapped as network drives in a Windows 10 client. If I encrypt those drives using bitlocker with the user account on the client, will it also be accessible for the admin account on the server? I want both users on the two machines to be able to access the encrypted content, how is it possible to do so?

Comment: See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83386/bitlocker-drive-encryption-not-secure-from-drive-mapping-on-network

Comment: @smwk, this has not yet been asked on SF. Maybe it would be good to answer it here and since you provided the link, maybe you'd like to give a short abstract that can then be marked as an answer, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapped drives are just Windows shares, so as long as the server can access the Bitlocker disks you can share the content to whoever you want.

Comment: Thanks! After checking the link you provided I realized that Bitlocker is basically a password/key-based encryption not tied to any Windows account; and after an encrypted drive is unlocked and opened, it behaves just like any other drives.